# Add pagination and sorting as a middleware in Mongoose (node.js, express RestAPI)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Is there a way to add limit, skip and sort parameters (as shown below) to all requests without having to define them for each endpoint (kinda like a middleware)? I want my requests to check for a limit, skip and sortBy parameter in the query URL and add the appropriate parameters accordingly.

```
// Fetch all movies: GET /
router.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const movies = await Movie.find().limit(req.query.limit).skip(req.query.skip).sort({title: 1});
    res.json(movies);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you write a common function and pass your query params to it and return the mongoosequery based on the query params you passed to the function and re-use the function everywhere. That solves the problem right

Comment: Thanks! I guess that is kinda what I did (see my solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a decent solution: I made a SearchOptions class which took in the query and held the parameters I wanted:

```
class SearchOptions {
    limit: number | null;
    skip: number | null;
    sort: object | null;

    constructor(query: any) {
        this.limit = query.limit ? parseInt(query.limit) : null;
        this.skip = (query.page && this.limit) ? (parseInt(query.page)-1) * this.limit : null;
        this.sort = {};

        if(query.sortBy) {
            const sortStr = query.sortBy.split(':');
            this.sort[sortStr[0]] = sortStr[1] === 'desc' ? -1 : 1
        } 
    }
}

export default SearchOptions;
```

Then I simply created a new instance of the object in my route:

```
// Fetch all movies: GET /
router.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const movies = await Movie.find({}, null, new SearchOptions(req.query));
    res.json(movies);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```